Vuetify Failed to resolve component
EDIT - I have looked at the "duplicate" questions and neither answer this question. The solution to this is not provided.
I'm using vuetify and am getting 'Failed to resolve component':
/**
 * main.ts
 *
 * Bootstraps Vuetify and other plugins then mounts the App`
 */

// Plugins
import { registerPlugins } from '@/plugins'
import {VueFire, VueFireAuth} from 'vuefire'

// Components
import App from './App.vue'

// Composables
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import {fbapp} from "./fstore";
import {router} from "./router";
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
import 'vuetify/styles'
import {vuetify} from "./vuetify";

// Composables

const vfOptions = {
  firebaseApp: fbapp,
  modules: [ VueFireAuth() ]
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(vuetify)
app.use(VueFire, vfOptions)
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app')

and
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'

// https://vuetifyjs.com/en/introduction/why-vuetify/#feature-guides
export const vuetify = createVuetify({
  // theme: {
  //   defaultTheme: 'dark',
  // },
  components,
  directives
})

There are 2 other SO questions that are the same, but the solutions are either people didn't pass the components and directives to the createVuetify method or they didn't use(vuetify) when composing their app. I'm doing both, can anyone see what I'm missing?

The code you posted looks fine, can you add the code that fails?

"and am getting" - please, list the full error.

do you have import vuetify, { transformAssetUrls } from 'vite-plugin-vuetify' and vue({       template: { transformAssetUrls }     }),     vuetify({       autoImport: true     }), in your vite config? I don't think you need to import * from vuetify. they should be imported automatically

here is Vite + Vue3 + Vuetify3 config I use:
vite.config.js
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import vuetify, { transformAssetUrls } from 'vite-plugin-vuetify'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: { transformAssetUrls }
    }),
    vuetify({
      autoImport: true
    })
  ]
})

plugins/vuetify.ts:
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
import 'vuetify/styles'

import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'

export default createVuetify({})

main.ts:
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify'

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(vuetify)

app.mount('#app')


In this case you only need to import labs components manually
